# Фоновые задачи, воркеры, интерфейс

Tags: python, веб-программирование, gui, cron

Я пишу рассылку сообщений. Эмулируется приложение андроид, и производится рассылка 1 аккаунт каждые 30 минут. Планируется использовать `10-50-100` аккаунтов. Бот запускается из командной строки: `php` или `python` commands. Я не понимаю, как мне рассылать сообщения из нескольких аккаунтов? Я Читал про `supervisor`, `workers`, фоновое выполнение команд, `cron` и не знаю что лучше использовать и какой язык программирования выбрать. Информации в гугле очень мало, примеров на **GitHub** тоже не нашел готовых приложений с интерфейсом.

Делаю для себя, запускать из терминала неудобно, планировал написать простой интерфейс для **Flask** для запуска команд и статистики выполнения. Как это делается вообще? Что почитать?

Comment: Написал с помощью cron. Но для одного аккаунта заводить однин файл и задание cron как-то глупо. Может кто подскажет инфой?